# UIActionSheet not showing in window ios8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, uiactionsheet

I have upgraded my project but its strange that UIActionSheet not showing in window.

```
  UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[actionImageProcess showInView:window];
```

What's the another solution for that..

Comment: But you are not showing the action sheet from the window. You are showing it from `self.view` (a view controller?).

Comment: Sorry I just changed the code..

Comment: I had the same problem (and a few others) with `UIActionSheet` under iOS 8. I ended up switching to `UIAlertController` and showing the action sheet from anything other than the window.

Comment: Your code worked for me when I invoked it in a button method (in Xcode 6.0.1). Where do you have this code? Are you sure actionImageProcess is not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar Can you check one more thing in my app - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex method call two times

Comment: are you facing the same problem

Comment: No, I am not having that problem; the delegate method is called only once.

Comment: It's a regression. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061964/uiactionsheet-not-showing-in-ios-8?stw=2

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because Apple changed internal implementation of UIActionSheet. Please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/index.html)

Important: UIActionSheet is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note that UIActionSheetDelegate is also deprecated.) To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet.

Subclassing Notes

UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:.